# Should I tag all questions about PrimeFaces as jsf?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should I tag all questions about [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) with tag [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf)? This was suggested me in other question about why my questions are not visited. It was suggested, that many users are filtering the questions by tags, and they will for example ignore everything not tagged [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf), even if they are self **PrimeFaces** experts.

On the other side, PrimeFaces specific questions, for example about PrimeFaces special components, will be of no interest to non-primefaces JSF users, so tagging them as JSF-specific could be condidered by them unnecessary spamming.

So, I'm looking for the *savoir-vivre* rule for tagging. Should I be more precise and specific, concentrating on experts, or add more general tags to attract broader audience?

To make things clear, I'm not asking if should I use [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) or [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf)? I'm asking should I use [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces) only or both.

Comment: Why do you phrase it as an either or?  Tag it with both.